# Is there a good reason to create an additional table to realize a 1:N relation?

Tags: database-design, relations

I have the following tables:

```
Users
_____
UserID
Data
...
```

```
Roles
_____
RoleID
Data
...
```

```
UsersRoles
_____
UserID
RoleID
```

`Users` and `Roles` are in a M:N relationship. As such I have the `UsersRoles` table to connect them.

Not connected to the previously mentioned tables, I also created the following tables:

```
Invoices
_____
InvoiceID
Data
...
```

```
Items
_____
ItemID
InvoiceID
Data
...
```

In this case I did not create an additional table since I am realizing a 1:N relationship here. My question is, if there is any reason for me to remove the `InvoiceID` from `Items` and create an `InvoicesItems` table similar to the `UsersRoles` table to connect them, even though I would not need it.

Comment: What is "positions" in this context?  Also: always name the row identifiers "Ids" with the appropriate context (`UserId`,`RoleId`,etc.)

Comment: A position is basically one line in an invoice with a designated product name, quantity, price, tax etc. Of course, a position is only used for a specific invoice. edit: I think the proper term would be "item".

Comment: `Item` could be a number of things, `InvoiceItem` or `InvoiceLine` is a more common convention.

Comment: I agree, but for the sake of the question I will leave it like it is. The context does not really matter here I think. I could also swap ```Invoice``` for ```Department``` and ```Item``` for ```Employee``` where one employee works for one department and a department has multiple employees. If I call the ```Items``` table ```InvoiceItems```, my question is harder to read.

Comment: *if there is any reason for me to remove the InvoiceID from Items and create an InvoicesItems table similar to the UsersRoles table to connect them, even though I would not need it.* Depends on prognosis to the future of your system. If you think that it is absolutely impossible that somewhere in future the relation may be transfered from 1:N to M:N then change nothing else change the scheme.

Comment: It is impossible that the relation will ever change. I thank you for your advice but can you list some pros and cons that aren't immediately obvious, maybe? I am relatively new to DB management, so I don't know about long-term effects of certain designs.

Comment: @Alpha context is *crucial* in databases, examples without appropriate context are bound to lead others to provide incorrect answers and you'll be as lost as you are now.  If you need an invoicing system, buy one of the shelf.

Comment: While I agree with you that is is crucial, I was trying to make an example to make my question easier to understand. If that went backwards, I am sorry. I could rephrase the question to make it a little more general: "Should I create an additional table to connect two tables in a 1:N relationship?" Your last sentence does not help me either, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even though I would not need it.

No. If you add it without any expectation of needing it, then it only serves to:

- Add overhead when querying the data
- Add overhead when adding or updating data
- Cause confusion for other people working on the DB
- Be a potential source of inconsistent data and other bugs

On the other hand if you think it is likely that there will be a need for the relationships to become many-to-many in future, for instance a line item being on multiple invoices due to partial payments or refunds, then there *may* be a case for adding the extra structure now to save on refactoring effort later but I would be wary of adding it from the start because of the above reasons unless I was very sure it was going to be needed at some point soon.

If you do add the extra structure but don't want to allow many-to-many to be a thing just yet, you have extra work to define constraints that enforce the desired one-to-many behaviour until it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why a few designers make this choice.

- Because they think the relationship may be modeled as M:N in the near future.
- Because the relationship is optional, and they wish to avoid using NULLS.

Whether either of these reasons are sound ones or not is somewhat subjective.

Comment: The first point is now clear to me thanks to the other answer as well. The second point is also interesting. I already assumed that it is a subjectively based decision, but I wanted to be sure.